# Change Illustrator's "Exit Full Screen mode" Escape keyboard shortcut

Tags: adobe

I'm getting really tired of this "shortcut" in Illustrator where you press "escape" and the window changes view mode from full screen/maximized to another.

Illustrator lists it as "Exit Full Screen Mode" in [this article here](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/default-keyboard-shortcuts.html). But the option does not exist under Edit > Keyboard shortcuts.

Does anyone know how to disable this apparent "feature"?